# Same type query at same table taking different time to execute MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am having few queries on the same table. But first one is taking 2 MS while others are taking hardly 390μs. I can't find out the reason. I am using MariaDb 10.2

Taking 2 Microsecond

```
select `ask_price` from `trades` where (`coin` = 'HLCN' and `market` = 'ETH') order by `time` desc limit 1
```

Others below Taking hardly 390μs

```
select `ask_price` from `trades` where (`coin` = 'BTC' and `market` = 'ETH') order by `time` desc limit 1

select `ask_price` from `trades` where (`coin` = 'BCH' and `market` = 'ETH') order by `time` desc limit 1
```

why the first one is taking upto 2-3 MS !

Comment: Can you show the explain plan?

Comment: 2 _microseconds_ is unlikely; perhaps you meant 2 _milliseconds_ (2000 microseconds)?

Answer (score 0):

Question is why  first case is fast, but if you need, that this query was generally fast and if you don't have already index for those columns, you can try:

```
create index idx_name on `trades`(`coin`,`market`,`time`);
```

and then run your query.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why queries change speed. In your case, it's most likely due to **disk page caching**, or **query caching**.

1. Disk Page Caching occurs at the OS level. Once the disk pages are loaded into memory, then the second query doesn't need to load them again, until they become stale, they are evicted, or you restart the database engine.
2. Query Caching is done by the database engine itself. As long as the data itself is not modified (no inserts, no updates, no deletes), the query result is still valid, and there's no need to execute the *same* query again. The result from the previous execution is just sent back to the client.

But, there are many other options. Low level database tricks are quite useful, so you can't really find out all that is happening, unless you decide to become a MySQL or MariaDB programmer.